# change ec2 public hostname even after restart the instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

my EC2 DNS public name is always change whenever I stop and start the instance. I wonder if there is a way to set a hostname for the instance like abc.com so that the hostname will not change even if I stop/restart the instance?
Thanks
Hong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to assign an Elastic IP address: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

That will keep the public hostname and IP address from changing when you reboot. Then if you want a nice name like "abc.com" you can go buy one and then point the domain at your server's Elastic IP.